# "No route matches" error?

Tags: testing, rspec, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new Rspec and just started by generating a new controller on Rails 3. It generates some Rspec tests by default. I have a question about how to make them pass though. As it stands, I see this test in my terminal"

> 1) BuildingsController GET 'show'
>   should be successful
>
> ```
>  Failure/Error: get 'show'
>  No route matches {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"show"}
>  # ./spec/controllers/buildings_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

However, I don't understand why it's coming up because I already have this route created ("resources :buildings"), and I ran `rake routes` and made sure it's there.

> building GET /buildings/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"buildings"}

What is necessary to make this pass? Here is the test by the way:

```
  describe "GET 'show'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'show'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to pass id of existing building: `get :show, :id => @building.id`

Routes complain about it because `:id` isn't optional.

Comment: You might also have an issue if the id has to be explicit in your route: `get :show, :building_id=> @building.id`