# No route matches with valid object

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Having read this:
["No route matches" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628103/rspec-no-route-matches-error)

I'm trying to figure out if there is a gem or way to monkey patch actionpack to get around this constraint.

Basically, I'm writing specs (they run fast), and I don't understand why actionpack throws this error when being applied to an object which isn't "saved".

For two reasons:

1. Why is it throwing a "No route matches" when it really should be throwing something more meaningful (e.g. object must be saved before a route can be constructed, or object ID is nil). The exception seems a little obscure.
2. I shouldn't have to save the object at all if all I am trying to do is generate a url for that object, given the ID is populated using a factory or something similar.

This constraint makes it a pain to write fast tests, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Show us your drawers... I mean code

Comment: I got around the problem. I was using mocha but found that unless you mocked specifically what the routing framework wanted, it wouldn't generate a path.

Comment: rspec mocks was what I reverted to and I don't seem to be getting these issues anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, the error message is a bit obscure. Regarding your second point, you don't need to save an object to generate a URL, the helper will work just as well with a literal value.

```
building_path(1) # GET /buildings/1 => BuildingsController#show, params={:id=>"1"}
```

So in the example the object can be replaced with any value:

```
get :show, :id => "1"
```

For example, if you use `rails generate scaffold Article`, RSpec will build a spec like this:

```
  def mock_article(stubs={})
    (@mock_article ||= mock_model(Article).as_null_object).tap do |article|
      article.stub(stubs) unless stubs.empty?
    end
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    it "assigns the requested article as @article" do
      Article.stub(:find).with("37") { mock_article }
      get :show, :id => "37"
      assigns(:article).should be(mock_article)
    end
  end
```

which does not hit the database.