# RSpec "No routes matches"

Tags: rest, rspec, routes

I'm trying to write a request spec for a custom action on one of my controllers.

My routes.rb is like this:

```
resources :cars do
  member do
    get :search
  end
end
```

My cars_controller.rb is like this:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def search
    # pending 
  end
end
```

My controller_cars_spec.rb is like this:

```
describe CarsController do
  describe 'Search' do
    it 'should call the model method that perform search by brand' do
      get :search
    end  
  end
end
```

The rake routes says:

```
search_car GET    /cars/:id/search(.:format) {:action=>"search", :controller=>"cars"}
```

and autotest say:

```
Failures:
1) CarsController Search should call the model method that perform search by brand
   Failure/Error: get :search
   ActionController::RoutingError:
     No route matches {:controller=>"cars", :action=>"search"}
   # ./spec/controllers/cars_controller_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What's the problem? I can't solve this failure...

Comment: Sorry... cars_controllers.rb and cars_controllers_spec.rb. It was a transcription error, but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an :id parameter to the route in your spec file, as seen in this post:
["No route matches" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628103/no-route-matches-error)

```
get :search, :id => @car.id
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, this should do what you want:

```
get :search, :car_id => @car.id
```

When you're using resources, you'll need to match the routes for each of the parameters, but that's not quite all of the story. Something like:

```
get :search, :id => @car.id
```

Seems like it would work, but doesn't.

When working with the resource(s) helper, ids are namespaced by prefixing the name of the resource for any subroutes and resources. I'm not entirely sure why the rspec error doesn't complain about missing :car_id, maybe someone else can fill in that missing part of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

`member` is for a single resource so it expects an :id. You want:

```
resources :cars do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

Comment: The phrase 'should call the model method that perform search by brand'
implies that I search for many cars of ONE brand... Sorry for my bad English language

Comment: I may still be completely misunderstanding what you're trying to do, so sorry if I'm muddying the waters. You have set up the custom controller action as a "member" as opposed to a "collection" and I believe that's incorrect for what you are trying to accomplish. A route defined as a member action is going to expect a car id and that's exactly the error you see in your test. If you want to search, not for a specific car, but a general car search, you want to define the action in a collection block as I illustrated. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

check if

```
resources :cars
```

is before

```
match '/cars/:id/search' => 'cars#search'
```